# My viewcontroller does not conform to GMSFetcherAutocompleteDelegate protocol

Tags: swift, google-places-api, swift3, xcode8-beta3

I'm trying to build an app where I input text into a `textField` and get the auto predict that google provides with its Fetcher GooglePlaces API. I have copied the code and altered it for my app but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using Swift Xcode8 Beta 3.

Please see my code below.

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces
import GoogleMaps

class NewTripAddCitiesViewController: UIViewController {

    var fetcher: GMSAutocompleteFetcher?
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var placesTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var addToTripLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var addCitiesLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func addPlaceToTable(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func savePlaces(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addCitiesLabel.text = "Please select which places you'd like to visit in \(tripCountry):"
        addToTripLabel.setTitle("Add to \"\(tripName)\"", for: [])

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white()
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

        // Set bounds to inner-west Sydney Australia.
        let neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.843366, longitude: 151.134002)
        let swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.875725, longitude: 151.200349)
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: neBoundsCorner, coordinate: swBoundsCorner)

        // Set up the autocomplete filter.
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .establishment

        // Create the fetcher.
        fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: bounds, filter: filter)
        fetcher!.delegate = self

        placesTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width - 5.0, height: 44.0))
        placesTextField?.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        placesTextField?.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("textFieldDidChange:")), for: .editingChanged)

        textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 45.0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height - 45.0))
        textView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        textView?.text = "No Results"
        textView?.isEditable = false

        self.view.addSubview(placesTextField!)
        self.view.addSubview(textView!)
    }

    func textFieldDidChange(placesTextField: UITextField) {
        fetcher?.sourceTextHasChanged(placesTextField.text!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension NewTripAddCitiesViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {

    func didAutocompleteWithPredictions(predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
        let resultsStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
        for prediction in predictions {
            resultsStr.append(prediction.attributedPrimaryText)
            resultsStr.append(AttributedString(string: "\n"))
        }
        textView?.attributedText = resultsStr
    }

    func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: NSError) {
        textView?.text = error.localizedDescription
    }

}
```

Comment: PS I am getting the error here: extension NewTripAddCitiesViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {

Comment: Well, just go ahead and implement the protocol methods the compiler is complaining about. You should see them in the issues navigator.

Comment: Whenever you run into this problem , just CMD+CLIK on the delegate, which will take you to its documentation and there you will see a bunch of function, just add those

Comment: I did that... The protocol requires the didAutocompleteWithPredictions method and the didFailAutocompleteWithError method, both of which I am using in the code... Could it be something related with a bridging header??? I am very new to this. I even made a new viewcontroller and copied the code directly from google developers verbatim but still get the same error... so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

> func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: NSError) {

has changes to

> public func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: Error) {